# The Molecular Level - DIY signal interceptor without faction help?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm trying to do [The Molecular Level](http://www.dtgre.com/2015/11/fallout-4-build-signal-interceptor-diy.html) quest but I seem to have run into a problem.

I've gotten the plans from Virgil but I don't have the ["special" tab](http://segmentnext.com/2015/11/11/fallout-4-workshop-items-unlock-guide-requirements-how-to/) from the workshop interface to build any of the components. Is there something I need to do to unlock the special tab?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be allied with a faction from what I can tell, then talk to their tech specialist.

You should be able to do it with the Minutemen if you've taken back the Castle.

The possible factions are the Minutemen, The Institute, Brotherhood of Steel and Railroad.

I personally used BoST build it, but a plot twist has made me consider stabbing them in the back.  Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

The "faction-less" method for The Molecular Level is using the Minutemen. If you show the blueprints to Sturges he will unlock the various structures in the Special section of the Workshop menu.

Comment: Sturges wants me to build a water pump or some crap. Do I have to do the whole building tutorial before he will look at the plans?

Comment: Have you skipped all of the settlement stuff up to now? You're going to need power generators at least in order to power the device you're going to build... Since I spent a lot of time on settlements before I proceeded with the question, speaking to Sturges resulted in stuff appearing in the menu instantly for me...

Comment: I built everything up at the red rocket gas station and ignored the sanctuary quest line.  I seem to have everything else I need including a number of different generators. 

http://fallout4.wiki.fextralife.com/The+Molecular+Level

Comment: Do you get the special workshop menu at the Red Rocket Gas Station?

Comment: I do not unfortunately. I'm in the middle of doing the sanctuary questline to see if sturg will look at the plans afterward

Comment: Did the full sanctuary workshop quest line and sturges still doesn't have an option to look at the plans.

Comment: The special menu appeared when I built Murphy's chair but it didn't contain the parts necessary for the quest. Only the chair.

Comment: Have you tried speaking to Preston first?

Comment: I did. He mentioned the minute men could help. And I didn't explore further since I'm trying to do this without a faction.

Comment: @gnarbarian you have to talk to preston first, he will escalate you to sturges.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it all by yourself - it seems to work to first go to one of the tech specialists and then buy back the signal interception plans. The quest log will reset and you are able to start building the reflector by yourself.

Comment: I will roll back my save and see if that works

Comment: I reverted my save and tried doing this with the minuteman specialist. but it looks like I can't buy the plans back. It is not listed in his inventory.